# Contains() in XPATH both Tag name and value of attribute

Tags: oracle, select, xpath

I have the an XML Column and it is similiar to the one mentioned below.

```
<appl>
<sftp_job name = "test1_ftp">
<ftp_job name = "test2_ftp">
<link name="testlink1">
<tag name ="task1_ftp">
<unix_job name="test123_ftp">
</appl>
```

My requirement is to get the value of all the atrributes that ends with "_ftp" like mentioned below.

```
test1_ftp
test2_ftp
task1_ftp
test123_ftp
```

I have the below SQL statement and it is working fine.

```
SELECT JOB_NAME
  FROM
    (SELECT q.jobname AS JOB_NAME
     FROM DFTAB1
     LEFT JOIN xmltable('/appl/*[contains(name(),"_job") or 
                                 contains(name(),"link") or 
                                 contains(name(),"task") ]' 
   PASSING XMLTYPE(DEF) columns jobname VARCHAR2(20) path '@name')q ON (1=1)
     )
 WHERE JOB_NAME LIKE '%_ftp%'
```

and this is working.

Is there a way that I can do in a single SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine boolean operators inside your XPath query:

```
SELECT x.job_name
FROM DFTAB1 d
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  '/appl/*[(contains(name(),"_job")
    or contains(name(),"link")
    or contains(name(),"task"))
    and (ends-with(@name, "_ftp"))]' 
  PASSING XMLTYPE(d.DEF)
  COLUMNS job_name VARCHAR2(20) path '@name'
) x;
```

I've used a cross join instead of a left outer join, which was essentially an inner join anyway, and effectively a cross join because of the dummy condition. I've also just called the generated column what you want it to end up as, so you don't need the alias.

Demo with your sample XML (with tag closures)

```
with DFTAB1 (DEF) as (
  select '<appl>
<sftp_job name = "test1_ftp" />
<ftp_job name = "test2_ftp" />
<link name="testlink1" />
<tag name ="task1_ftp" />
<unix_job name="test123_ftp" />
</appl>' from dual
)
SELECT x.job_name
FROM DFTAB1 d
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  '/appl/*[(contains(name(),"_job")
    or contains(name(),"link")
    or contains(name(),"task"))
    and (ends-with(@name, "_ftp"))]' 
  PASSING XMLTYPE(d.DEF)
  COLUMNS job_name VARCHAR2(20) path '@name'
) x;

JOB_NAME            
--------------------
test1_ftp
test2_ftp
test123_ftp
```

which is the same result your original query gets; `task1_ftp` isn't included because `tag` doesn't match your original `contains` checks.

There is a slight difference, but I think from the question wording this is actually correct and your original wasn't quite. When you do `LIKE '%_ftp%'` the underscore is also a single-character wildcard, so that would match say `abcftp`, which I don't think you wanted. The equivalent would be escaped, as `LIKE '%\_ftp%' ESCAPE '\'`.

A more significant change, as MTO mentioned, is that your query looks for `_ftp` (or, as mentioned above, in fact just `ftp`) anywhere in the job name. Your question actually says 'ends with "_ftp"' so your description and query don't match. If you do want it anywhere in the attribute value, just use `contains` again instead of `ends-with`:

```
SELECT x.job_name
FROM DFTAB1 d
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  '/appl/*[(contains(name(),"_job")
    or contains(name(),"link")
    or contains(name(),"task"))
    and (contains(@name, "_ftp"))]' 
  PASSING XMLTYPE(d.DEF)
  COLUMNS job_name VARCHAR2(20) path '@name'
) x;
```

though the result is the same with your sample.

Comment: The OP's original query is `LIKE '%_ftp%'` so it does not just match `_ftp` at the end of the string but anywhere in the string.

Comment: True, not sure if that was a mistake too; the wording in the question is "ends with "_ftp"" so I went with that. If it should be anywhere then `ends-with` can just be changed to `contains`.

Comment: Thanks All, I changed the code like below, but its not working,xmltable('/appl/*[contains(name(),"_job") or contains(name(),"link") or contains(name(),"task") and contains(@name,"ftp") ]'

Comment: What does "not  working" mean? Notice the extra parentheses I added to my version, to control the precedence of the 'or' and 'and'.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I got it Right now. I mixed up with Cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT q.jobname AS JOB_NAME
FROM   DFTAB1 d
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/appl/*[contains(name(),"_job") or 
                  contains(name(),"link") or 
                  contains(name(),"task") ]' 
         PASSING XMLTYPE(d.DEF)
         columns jobname VARCHAR2(20) path '@name'
       ) q
WHERE  q.JOBNAME LIKE '%_ftp%'
```